Unable to Install and Update packages in gitlab-ci-yml
I have a gitlab-ci-yml script to deploy in my remote server, but I got a problem when installing ssh, I already force assigned the DNS but still the same problem and tried different image in docker but nothing works.

gitlab runner:

  [[runners]]
  name = "deployment_runner"
  url = "http://mygitlab-url/"
  id = 9
  token = "aFcyz1PhKjE1CcPvg8E3"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-12-09T02:53:50Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:20.04"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
    extra_hosts = ["host"]
    dns = ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]


gitlab-ci-yml:

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment_runner
    
  only: 
    - development
  before_script:
    - echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
    - echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
    - cat /etc/resolv.conf
    - apt-get clean
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y dnsutils
    - nslookup archive.ubuntu.com
    - apt-get install -y openssh-client
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $SSH_HOST > ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  script:
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd $WORK_DIR && git pull origin development && sudo docker compose restart &&  exit"
  after_script:
    - rm -rf ~/.ssh

error:
20 $ echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
21 $ echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
22 $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
23 nameserver 8.8.8.8
24 nameserver 8.8.4.4
25 $ apt-get clean
26 $ apt-get update
27 Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
28 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
29 Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubunty focal-security InRelease
30 Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
31 Err: 3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
32 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
53 Err:4 http:archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
34 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
55 Reading package lists...
36 W: Failed to fetch http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
37 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
38 W: Failed to fetch http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
39 W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
40 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
41 $ apt-get install -y dnsutils
42 Reading package lists...
43 Building dependency tree...
44 Reading state information...
45 E: Unable to locate package dnsutils
47 Running after_script
48 Running after_script...
49 $ rm -rf ~/.ssh
51 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1


It looks like your Docker runner doesn't have network connectivity. I can't pinpoint the exact issue, but I noticed a couple of questionable configurations in your GitLab Runner setup:
extra_hosts = ["host"]

This format is incorrect. According to the documentation, it should follow the format: hostname:<ip address>. For example:
extra_hosts = ["other-host:127.0.0.1"]

network_mtu = 0

This value seems suspicious. I could only find one mention of this parameter in the documentation, and I recommend either removing it or setting a more typical value, such as 1492 — unless you have a specific reason to configure it this way.
For testing purposes, I suggest running any Docker container on the host where your GitLab Runner is installed to verify network connectivity. This will help you determine whether the issue lies with the host itself or with the runner configuration.
Lastly, a general suggestion: it's usually better to build a custom Docker image with all required packages (like dnsutils) and updates preinstalled. This avoids installing them every time you trigger a job, which can save time and reduce potential issues during the pipeline execution.
